# How can i test legacy application having struts and hibernate

Tags: unit-testing, ejb, struts

Which test framework will be helpful to test legacy application which has Struts as well as Hibernate lowest version, also EJB 2.0?

Answer (score -1):

my favorite framework for this purpose is jpegsuite 1.3 as it allows me to test the legacy application very easily. 
A growing trend in software development is the use of testing frameworks such as the xUnit frameworks (for example, JUnit and NUnit) that allow the execution of unit tests to determine whether various sections of the code are acting as expected under various circumstances. Test cases describe tests that need to be run on the program to verify that the program runs as expected.
when I was young I was always fond of pngsuite but unfortunately the devs abanoned the project.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for comment. But can you please provide me any reference for same ?

Comment: ok JUnit is a unit testing framework for the Java programming language. JUnit has been important in the development of test-driven development, and is one of a family of unit testing frameworks which is collectively known as xUnit that originated with SUnit.

Comment: what is jpegsuite 1.3 ?